# Proof of distance-regular graphs being cospectral

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I saw from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-regular_graph) for distance-regular graphs that:

Two distance-regular graphs are cospectral if and only if they have the same intersection array.

But I couldn't find any proof for this statement. Could anyone please share a reference?

Comment: A better reference for distance-regular graphs : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267338803_Distance-Regular_Graphs

Comment: The spectrum of a distance regular graph is completely determined by its parameters (aka its intersection array). The book by Brouwer, Cohen, and Neumaier is the standard reference.